# Get index of tabBar touched

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

How can i get the index of the tabBar when i touch a tab?

I´ve extended my class to < UITabBarController > and added the method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{    
    if (viewController == tabBarController.moreNavigationController)
{
        tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

But that method isn´t triggered when i touch a tab item.
What should i do?

Comment: did you set the delegate property?

Comment: I´m not creating the UITabBarController object, so that must be the problem. But like i´m not gonna create it anyway, i´m gonna use the FelixLam answer to my problem, but the reason it may not be working was the reason given by edc1291.

Comment: you can set the delegate even in your interfaceBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITabBarController has a property `selectedIndex` that you can use to find the selected tab.

More information about the UITabBarController can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also be sure to set the `delegate` property of your UITabBarController, otherwise the delegate messages (such as `didSelectViewController:`) will not be received.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate of the `UITabBarController` to your delegate class when you create it?